# In Mira Grant's "Newsflesh" series, what are the ten levels of "danger"?

Tags: mira-grant, newsflesh

In [Mira Grant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mira_Grant)'s [Newsflesh series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?26901), there are mentions of different areas having different "security levels", ranging from 1 to 10 (10 being safest). There are references to some of the levels explaining what they mean (I believe 10, 9, and 7 were explicitly described). Others are only alluded to. (They can decon you indefinitely for Level 2 exposure; they'll probably just shoot you for level 1).

Is there a list of what all the levels are?

Answer (score 2):

Other levels have not been defined in "Feed". But they may have been defined in "Deadline", which is its sequel (I have not read it). The sequel continues which the story of Shaun Mason from the first book.

Comment: No, there are no more levels defined in "Deadline". I don't expect there will be in the last book either, since I can't think of any reason the missing levels could be relevant to the plot.

Comment: And now that the trilogy is completed, it's fair to say we may never know.